# isKinematic and usegravity strange behaviour on script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to make a key fall and stop at a specific point, my key is inside a parent gameobject, i attached a script to that parent and a rigibody where i enabled gravity and iskinematic is false, in the script when it reaches a specific point on z i want to apss gravity to false and kinematic to true:
 **here is the code**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class keyRotate : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        transform.Rotate (0f,0f, 90f * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position.y < -277f)
            Debug.Log ("INNN");
            //rb.useGravity = false;
            //rb.isKinematic = true;
    }
}
```

the strange thing that is happening, is that when i comment the 2 last lines with the rb, the object fall and the debug.log shows, when i uncoment it the object stops falling and the debug never shows, shouldn't the message on debug show in this case the default value for gravity is true it should fall anyway :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add brackets { } to your if statement. Right now you just use the very next row after the if.